# Copy & paste variable rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that inserts a number of rows between existing lines of data:

```
Sub test()

Dim j As Long, r As Range
j = InputBox("No. of rows to be inserted?")
Set r = Range("A3")
Do
Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert

Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)

If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```

What I actually need it to do is insert copies of the lines 'x' number of times, not insert blank ones. Can anyone help? I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge in this!

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgXSW.png)
[After - AMENDED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEncZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    j = Application.InputBox("No. of rows to be inserted?", Type:=1)
    With Worksheets("REFS") '<-_| change "REFS" to your actual worksheet name
        i = 1
        With .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            Do While i <= .Rows.Count
                With .Cells(i).EntireRow
                    .Copy
                    .Offset(1).Resize(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With
                i = i + j + 1
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm using [Application.InputBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468(v=office.15).aspx) method instead of [VBA InputBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768(v=office.11).aspx) one because the former lets you force the user input data type (in the example Type:=1 forces *numeric* input)

Comment: That's great, thank you so much - but it only copies and inserts 'x' copies of the first row. I need it to jump to the next 'unique' row and do the same process until it hits a blank row - how do I loop this?

Comment: sorry I don't get you: Please explain in greater detail

Comment: Sorry - I'm not overly good at this! The original macro runs on a list of data. It inserts 'x' blank rows between each line of data. I need the lines inserted to be copies, not blank. Basically, the above answer works, but it takes the first line of data and makes 'x' copies below. I need it to move on to the next unique line ('x+1'?!) and insert x copies of this row. Then the next, and so on until it reaches a blank row.

Comment: just add some screenshots of "before" and "after" scenarios

Comment: I think I've done that, as I'm new they are showing as links not pictures.

Comment: What is the _"next unique line"_. How to understand how many copies to be inserted after each "unique" name (in your example Smith gets copied 8 times, Joes 16. And then there comes again Smith 5 times at the end). I can't see any clue whatsoever about how to pass from "before" to "after"

Comment: I've changed the picture (I'm worse at this than I thought!! Sorry!) - the next 'unique line' is the next line of new data after 'x' copies have been inserted. It would always be the same number of copies to insert for each unique data line (determined by the query box). Hope this makes vague sense now, apologies again, I'm learning, honest!!

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.